# Stopper in PowerShell (time elapse during excution of a program)

Tags: powershell

My machine is Win7 64 bit. I use PowerShell.

While running gcc or gfortran on my PowerShell I would like to see a 'stopper' (time elapsed) during my program is execute. How can I do that in PowerShell?

I would like that this stop-watch (time elapse) will be on the shell and not part of my code that i am running.

Is there any command? Do someone give me a script that do it (I am novice).

Answer (score 4):

If you want the time to be constantly displayed while the script(block) is running, you can do something like below:

```
function timer($script, $interval = 1){
    $t = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::startnew()
    $job = start-job -script $script
    while($job.state -eq "running"){
        write-host -fore yellow "Elapsed: $($t.elapsed) "
        $job | Receive-Job
        sleep $interval
    }
    $t.stop()
}

timer -script {1..10 | %{ write-host $_ test; start-sleep 2}}
```

Comment: HI manojlds,
Thanks for the script. But how can I use it?
foe example my file I want to run is a.exe so how I incorporate your script with this?

Comment: @user1091340 `timer -script { & $pathToYourExe}`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with the Write-Progress cmdlet:

```
$start = Get-Date
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {...}
do {
    Write-Progress "Waiting for Job to Finish" "Waiting For $((Get-Date) - $start)"
    Start-Sleep -milliseconds 250
} while ($j.State -eq 'Running')
Receive-Job -Job $j
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your requirement exactly...  If you want to find the time elapsed for a powershell cmdlet or a ps1 script that you run, you can compare the startexecutiontime and endexecutiontime property of the command history.

e.g. Use get-history to find the command you want to time, then use this

```
Get-history -ID 123 | % { $_.endexecutiontime - $_.startexecutiontime}
```

or if you want to find the time elasped for the last command, use this

```
get-history -count 1 | % { $_.endexecutiontime - $_.startexecutiontime}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to time a process. Replace $executable and $argument with your specifics. The $timeSpan variable will give you the time it took to complete.

```
$executable = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
$arguments = "C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log"

$timeSpan = Measure-Command { Start-Process -FilePath $executable -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow }

$timeSpan
```

Output:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 24
Milliseconds      : 255
Ticks             : 242559320
TotalDays         : 0.000280739953703704
TotalHours        : 0.00673775888888889
TotalMinutes      : 0.404265533333333
TotalSeconds      : 24.255932
TotalMilliseconds : 24255.932
```