# Why is the command in ScriptBlock not working?

Tags: powershell

I want to measure elapsed time from a cmdlet

```
Invoke-ASCmd
```

I am using it the following way

```
$elapsedTime = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $XMLF -Server "$Server[-1]" >$output_file
}
do {
    write-progress -activity "Syncing..." -status "$([string]::Format("Time Elapsed: {0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", $elapsedTime.Elapsed.hours, $elapsedTime.Elapsed.minutes, $elapsedTime.Elapsed.seconds))" 
    #-percentcomplete ($_/10);
    Start-Sleep -milliseconds 250
} while ($j.State -eq 'Running')
Receive-Job -Job $j

$elapsedTime.stop()
```

However, all i see on the console is a flashing blue progress bar that doesnt appear to be even elapsing the time at all...and frankly, i dont even think the scriptblock is being executed at all (the Invoke cmdlet)

why is that?

[image]

and it appears to last 1 second

[image: image2]

I know that the scriptblock is not working because the syncing is supposed to take at least 20 seconds so something is wrong

Also, i would like to get the percentage (circles animation/prgress), this is not working

```
-percentcomplete ($_/10);
```

One last thing, i would like to save the final elapsed time to a variable `$FinalTime`, would i do it inside the loop or outside?

I am combining these two answers here and modifying for my needs:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813370/8397835

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468024/8397835

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the progress is quick because it takes PowerShell 1 second to load the module before  erroring out. We can see the error message with `Receive-Job`:

```
PS C:\> Receive-Job $j
InputFile "" not found
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-ASCmd], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DataValidation,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ExecuteScriptCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

`InputFile "" not found` indicates that the variables were empty. They are empty because you can't reference variables directly inside of the Script Block. Using `Start-Job`, you must pass it into the Script Block as an argument, and receive it as a parameter inside the Script Block. Something like this:

```
$j = Start-Job -Arg $XMLF, $Server, $output_file -ScriptBlock {
    Param($XMLF, $Server, $output_file)
    Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $XMLF -Server "$Server" >$output_file
}
```

As for progress, since there is no "Direct" way to measure how far the progress is to 100%, we "fake it". Since we know that it takes about 20 seconds to execute, we simply have our progress do some math using the time from 0 to 20 as our 0 to 100 progress:

```
[Math]::Min(100*($elapsedTime.Elapsed.Seconds / 20),100)
```

Essentially use `$elapsedTime` for 0 to 100 percent over 20 seconds. That 20 seconds can be changed to any number that is close to the approximate execution time. Using `[Math]::Min` we ensure that if it takes longer than 20 seconds, the progress will show 100 percent, but the status will continue to show the time. So it would look like this:

```
do {
    write-progress -activity "Syncing..." -status "$($elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString())" -percentcomplete ([Math]::Min(100*($elapsedTime.Elapsed.Seconds / 20),100));
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
} while ($j.State -eq 'Running')
```

Comment: cant i just base the progress based on elapsed time of how long the Invoke-ASCmd cmdlet will take to finish executing (i.e. at which it outputs the file, that would be the end technically) instead of hardcoding a value like 20? this cube im testing with is small so it takes around 20 sec, but i have 20 other cubes that take longer even...i'd say up to 15 mins average, though as they grow in the future they could even take longer. i would like the value to be dynamic, isnt it possible? if not, how can i save the elapsed time at least in a variable so i can output it somewhere?

Comment: You *are* saving the elapsed time to a variable: `$elapsedTime`. Yup sure, you can replace the value "20" with a variable and put in any number you want in to make it dynamic. (e.g. you could put this whole thing inside a function).