# How do i measure percent completion based on when there is output file?

Tags: powershell

I am measuring elapsed time of the `Invoke-ASCmd` cmdlet using the following script:

```
$elapsedTime = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
$j = Start-Job -Arg $XMLF, $Server, $output_file -ScriptBlock {
    Param($XMLF, $Server, $output_file)
    Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $XMLF -Server "$Server" >$output_file
}
do {
    write-progress -activity "Syncing..." -status "$($elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString())" -percentcomplete ([Math]::Min(100*($elapsedTime.Elapsed.Seconds / 20),100));
    -Milliseconds 250
} while ($j.State -eq 'Running')
Receive-Job -Job $j

$elapsedTime.stop()
```

since there is no "Direct" way to measure how far the progress is to 100%, i am "faking it". Since it takes about 20 seconds to execute for the database i am testing on, I simply have the progress do some math using the time from 0 to 20 as 0 to 100 progress:

```
[Math]::Min(100*($elapsedTime.Elapsed.Seconds / 20),100)
```

However, its not always gonna be 20. so i cant hardcode the value like this, especially i have about 30 databases that all vary in size, and thus duration.

as such, i am thinking since there is not a way to measure the Inovke-ASCmd cmdlet, maybe i can somehow measure up to the elapsed time, or up to the time the file is outputted since thats when it indicates the end of the command i think.

Although, i dont know if that will be possible because technically it would have to somehow know the future when it finished, or when the file is gonna output, because it would need the value in there beforehand

something like a dynamic value:

```
[Math]::Min(100*($elapsedTime.Elapsed.Seconds / $DynamicValue),100)
```

Therefore, how can i do that?

also, the progress blue screen, i expect it to disappear after the elapsed time is complete...yet it persists on the console and stays there. how can i make it disappear once it done elapsing?

related: [Why is the command in ScriptBlock not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485853/why-is-the-command-in-scriptblock-not-working)

Comment: since Write-Progress is SLOW, why are you bothering with a progress bar with such short run times? if you NEED to have some sort of "things are running and not locked up", then just write a dot very second or so. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ok ill be fine with that, but i dont know how to do that

Comment: i think if you replace all the time & progress stuff with a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` and a `Write-Host '.' -NoNewLine`, it otta work. [*grin*]